# Datatable not updated where clause

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

My datatable is not updating for query with a where clause. Query is retrieving the data according to query, but the datatable not update for the query result. I'm using laravel 5.8 with yajrav datatable package. Ajax success got correct json values.

My ajax request:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btnShowToday', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let currentDate = $('#datepicker').val()

  $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: '/currentDateAppointment',
      data: {
        currentDate: currentDate
      }
    })
    .done(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
})
```

My Controller method:

```
    public function currentDateAppointments(Request $request)
    {
        $date = $request->get('currentDate');

        $getData = DB::table('customers')
        ->join('jobs', 'jobs.id', '=', 'customers.id')
        ->select('jobs.id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'vehiclemodel', 'date', 'time', 'payment_status', 'amount')
        ->where('date', '=', $date)
        ->get();

        $datatable = DataTables::of($getData)->make(true);
        return $datatable;
    }
```

ajax response:

[image]

first initialize of datatable to get all data from database:

```html
 $('#appointment-datatable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '/get_appointment_data',
                columns: 
                    [
                      {
                        data: 'id', 
                        name: 'id'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'firstname', 
                        name: 'firstname'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'lastname', 
                        name: 'lastname'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'vehiclemodel', 
                        name: 'vehiclemodel'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'date', 
                        name: 'date',
                        searchable: true
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'time', 
                        name: 'time'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'payment_status', 
                        name: 'payment_status'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'amount', 
                        name: 'amount'
                      },
                      {
                        data: null,
                        orderable: false,
                        render: function (data, type, full, meta) 
                        {
                            let id = data['id']
                            return '<button id="mdButtonViewService" value="'+id+'" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">View Services</button>'       
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        data: null,
                        orderable: false,
                        render: function (data, type, full, meta) 
                        {
                            let id = data['id']
                            return '<button id="mdButtonAssign" value="'+id+'" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Assign</button> <button id="mdButtonDelete" value="'+id+'" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>'       
                        }
                      }
                    ]

              })
```

why the datatable not showing the query result? ajax.reload() or draw() functions are not working. how to fix this? thank you.

Comment: do you get any error ?

Comment: no... no errors. ajax is success

Comment: Looks like ajax not passing your variables to function check values with ajax to see if they are full

Comment: my ajax is working and ajax success is true. do you know a method to refesh datatable?

Comment: refresh page or mysql ?

Comment: i added a screenshot of ajax response. Datatable is need to update with that data..

Comment: show also the code of datatable, how you display data in datatable?

Comment: I edited the question and added the code.

Answer (score 0):

"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"
This error comes because you didn't import the library most probably.

```
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is not a answer for my problem

Answer (score 0):

looks like ajax not passing variables try as folowing to validate to see if ajax getting values.

```
var firstname =$("firstname").val(); 
    if(username.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Empty.');
        $('#inputName').focus();
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
```

You can do somethinglike this to reload, under your ajax query.

```
 load();

 function load()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"/currentDateAppointment",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
```

> EDIT : including my codes in to yours,

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnShowToday', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let currentDate = $('#datepicker').val()

  $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: '/currentDateAppointment',
      data: {
        currentDate: currentDate
      }
    })
    .done(function(res) {
      console.log(res);

    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
load();
})

 function load()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"/currentDateAppointment",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#appointment-datatable').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
```

Comment: my ajax is successfully passing the values and query is getting the data, that is not the problem.

Comment: I dont see images you added due to : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Change in my answer : $('#appointment-datatable').html(data); To : in Marios Nikolaou code :  $('#appointment-datatable').DataTable( {
        data: data
       }); OR ( {
         data
       });

Answer (score 0):

On `ajax` call success update the datatable with requested data.Check my answer and let me know.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnShowToday', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let currentDate = $('#datepicker').val()

  $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: '/currentDateAppointment',
      data: {
        currentDate: currentDate
      }
    })
    .done(function(res){ 
       json_res = JSON.parse(res.data[0]);
       var table = $('#appointment-datatable').DataTable();
       table.rows.add(json_res).draw();
    }) 
    .fail(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
})
```

Comment: I tried your code it still the same, datatable not update... :(

Comment: @Hashan i have updated the answer, check the console it should print the json result

Comment: thanks for the code. ajax call returns the json responce with correct values, but the problem is datatable not updating with that json data? ajax success is true, how can i update the datatable on ajax success?

Comment: `$('#appointment-datatable').DataTable().destroy()`  this  code is working and datatable is destroying but draw() is not working.

Comment: you want data from json that start from `data:[{ "id":"1", "firstname:"kamal" ` right?

Comment: yes. ajax returns that data as a json respone. i want to update the datatable with that new data...

Comment: @Hashan look closer the photo with json result there is `#data` and inside another array `data:[{ "id":1 ...` , i think you do a mistake when getting the data from ajax call.

Comment: that is returned by Datatable laravel pakage, that can handle to datatable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204625/discussion-between-marios-nikolaou-and-hashan).